# Saving Modified Data in CloudKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I have been testing out CloudKit as i wish to release an app using it when the release of iOS8 occurs. It seems simple enough to save data using the code below:

```
CKRecordID * recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"basicRecord"];
CKRecord * record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"basicRecordType" recordID:recordID];
[record setValue:@"defaultValue" forKey:@"defaultKey"];
CKDatabase *database = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
[database saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Record Saved!");
    }
}];
```

and I receive no errors from this. However, if i try to run the code again, maybe because i have changed the record value to

```
[record setValue:@"newValue" forKey:@"defaultKey"];
```

I receive an error which begs the question, how do i go about saving a modified piece of data. After all, this is a fundamental part of saving things to the cloud. The error is below and any help would be greatly appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for further information.

```
Error: <CKError 0x17024afb0: "Server Record Changed" (14/2017); "Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x144684a80; basicRecord:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: (null)"; uuid = 182C497F-966C-418A-9E6A-5563BA6CC6CD; container ID = "iCloud.com.yourcompany.CloudKit">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error is probably because `saveRecord:` works only for new records or records that are newer than the version on the server:

> This method saves the record only if it has never been saved before or if it is newer than the version on the server. You cannot use this method to overwrite newer versions of a record on the server. [CKDatabase docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKDatabase_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKDatabase/saveRecord%3acompletionHandler%3a)

The recommended approach to modify an existing record (or set of records) is to use a `CKModifyRecordsOperation` set with the desired `savePolicy` to deal with conflicts:

> After modifying the fields of a record, use this type of operation object to save those changes to a database. (...)
>   When saving records, the value in the savePolicy property determines how to proceed when conflicts are detected on the server. [CKModifyRecordsOperation docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKModifyRecordsOperation)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [CKRecord](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html):

> New records exist only in memory until you explicitly save them to iCloud.

When you set the new value `[record setValue:@"newValue" forKey:@"defaultKey"];` you have already saved the record, making it invalid.

You can use `CKModifyRecordsOperation` and in most situations it might be preferrable but you don't have to. Just fetch your data using a fresh `CKRecord`, then feed that record into `saveRecord:` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/FetchingRecords/FetchingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH4-SW3).

Answer (score 0):

After you save the record, fetch it so that the retured record will then have the RecordID that Cloudkit added

Then on that same fetched record, use setValue to change the data you want to change

Then you can use CFModifyRecordsOperation 
In the example below, cachedCKRecordsServiceCenter contains the fetched records from cloudkit and those records have the CloudKit RecordID's in them......

```
           //find this service center in the cached records
            for (_,serviceCenter) in (theModel?.cachedCKRecordsServiceCenter.enumerated())! //is data for logged in Co ONLY with NO Co name attached
            {
                let name = serviceCenter["name"] as! String
                returnValue = "Try Again"
                if name == displayedRecordName
                {
                    serviceCenter.setValue(displayedRecordName! + "_" + (theModel?.companyName)!, forKey: "name") //db values have Co name appended
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label2Text.text, forKey:"street1")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label3Text.text, forKey:"street2")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label4Text.text, forKey:"city")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label5Text.text, forKey:"state")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label6Text.text, forKey:"zip")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label7Text.text, forKey:"phone")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label8Text.text, forKey:"email")
                    serviceCenter.setValue(label9Text.text, forKey:"note")

                    let saveRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation()

                    var ckRecordsArray = [CKRecord]()
                    // set values to ckRecordsArray
                    ckRecordsArray.append(serviceCenter)

                    saveRecordsOperation.recordsToSave = ckRecordsArray
                    saveRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .ifServerRecordUnchanged

                    appDelegate.locked = true
                    saveRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            // Really important to handle this here
                            ////////print("ERROR: Unable to update Driver Location: Error= \(error)")
                            self.returnValue = "ERROR: Unable to update Driver Location: ERROR = \(error)"
                            self.appDelegate.locked=false
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             ////print("Successfully updated Service Center")
                            self.appDelegate.locked=false
                            self.returnValue = "Successfully updated Service Center"
                            self.appDelegate.locked=false

                            //reget the data into the cach
                            self.theModel?.fetchServiceCenterFromCloudKit1()
                        }

                    }

                    CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(saveRecordsOperation)
                }
            }
```