# CoreData Sync with CloudKit or iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using Swift 4 and I have 3 to 4 CoreData entities in my project. I want to sync CoreData with iCloud for sharing on other devices and also for a backup of data.

I have seen more questions on StackOverflow related this but not found any solution in Swift 3 or Swift 4. I think CoreData to iCloudKit sync is deprecated but what are the other solutions for this? How can I sync my CoreData data on iCloud?

Thanks.

Comment: CoreData sync options have been covered in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820690/how-to-sync-records-between-core-data-and-cloudkit-efficiently).